# "The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page" after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I think i have already read all the related questions here, but sadly i couldn't find an answer yet.

My problem is, locally everything runs fine without errors but when i deploy my website to my server, i'm getting there the following error:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page >"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "styles"
```

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 4 with the Razor engine and .Net 4.5.

In `_Layout.cshtml` i have the following block defined:

```
<head>
    ....
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
</head>
```

And in `Index.cshtml` the following block:

```
@section styles{
   <link rel="stylesheet" href=... />
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js/somejs")
}
```

This is driving me crazy. If this error would also occur on my development machine, i could debug it. But it only happens on my server, locally everything runs fine.

Even other projects with similar code pieces run fine on my server.

Maybe someone has any hints for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the contents of the `_Layout.cshtml` or `Index.cshtml` on your server is not what you think it is. Maybe the deployed version is different than what you have locally. Deployment went wrong?

Comment: I'm using the integrated "Web Deployment" and deployed already about 20 times.
I'll try to deploy it directly and see if that makes any difference.
 Still strange that it only happens to this project and not to the others that are quit similar.

Comment: Found it. It was indeed something wrong with the deployment. In the properties of the `_Layout.cshtml` the buildhandling was set to 'none' instead of 'content'. Although i have no idea how that happend in the first place, it was a really simple fix. 

Thanks for pointing me in this direction!